# Migrated AF app to .NET 7 Isolated Process; now getting 502 errors for a few minutes while app warms up

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I had an app on .NET 6 in Azure App Service Consumption plan and all worked great until the moment I migrated it to .NET 7, which requires isolated hosting. I created a brand new AF in Azure under the same subscription; besides the .NET version being set to Isolated, however, everything else is the same including the code.

[image]

Problem is: I started getting 502 errors ("bad gateway") for the first few minutes of running my functions in the newly created AF. When it's woken it works well until I make it idle again for few hours. Note that there is no "Always On" option in the Consumption plan.

My question is if it's an expected behavior for the plan—though I did not experience it in the Consumtion plan in .NET 6—and I should invest into a Premium plan with "Always on", or if it's not supposed to happen and I need to tweak something in the settings or open a ticket with Microsoft?

Comment: There might be an issue with the accounts active directory access with respect to the subscription of the current account. Check with the screenshot which shows the warning message to check with the ADD issue. Resolve those and grant access to all the services for the subscription. [image](https://i.imgur.com/b7N8iZn.png)

Comment: I do not think it's applicable to my configuration, I have all serverless, I do not have dedicated servers. When I go to the "Azure Migrate" screen I see the warning but nothing  shown under it, when I click around: databases, web apps, vdi they are all empty

Comment: Is your Azure Function `.NET 6` or `.NET 6 isolated` ?

Comment: hi @Harshitha, like I said in the question, I started experiencing the issue after migration to .NET 7 isolated, I did not have such issue on .NET 6. So I did the steps you described below, and only then I started getting 502 errors. Sounds like something wrong with Azure infra, going to create a support ticket with Ms

Comment: @YMC Did you find the solution? At the moment, I got exactly the same problem. I hope that you found an easy solution. Otherwise I need to create a support ticket with MS too.

Comment: nope, the connection hiccups keeps going, not super critical for me though since not prod yet. I've not filed ticket to support either. My plan is to wait for .NET 8 support for AF and rebuild it on .NET 8 and recreate the function. .NET release is planned for Nov 2023

Comment: @OscarVeldman if you file a ticket with Ms Support, I would appreciate if you add few words on the ticket resolution statement, it could help other folks that run into the same issue. thanks

Comment: @YMC My azure functions project was created three months ago. From the start I got the hiccups in Azure. After trying some a couple solutions with the MS support last few days. I could finally fix hiccups by upgrading to the latest 'Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker' nuget packages including ''Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.sdk'. Could you verify that too? I think MS fixed something in the last few months properly.

Comment: that would be very good news if it's fixed. Thank you for letting me know. I'll check it up when I have a chance, and report it here

Answer (score 1):

Check the below steps to migrate the `Azure Function 6` to `Azure Function 7` Isolated Process.

- Created Azure Function`.NET 6`
  [image]

***.NET6 Output***

[image]

- Migrated from Azure Function `.NET 6` to `.NET 7 Isolated`.
- ***While Migrating lot of changes has to be done in the existing files.***
- In `Visual Studio` => `.csproj` file, change the `TargetFramework` from `net6.0` to `net7.0`.
- In `.csproj`,Remove the NuGet package `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`  . This package is meant to be used with `in-proc` function apps and not in isolated function apps.
- Add the below Nuget packages.

```cs
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0" />
```

- In `Function1.cs` file, update the new using statements and change the class names.

***.csproj file***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
 
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

***My Sample Function1.cs***

```cs
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
```

Add the new file `Program.cs`

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .Build();
host.Run();
```

- Save and publish the build with new changes.
- I am able to access the new Function App with .NET 7 without any issues.
- In `local.settings.json` file, change the `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` from `dotnet` to `dotnet-isolated`.
- You can see the changes in the deployed App.

[image]

- We can change the configurations in `Azure Portal` => `Configuration` => `Application Settings`.

[image]

- But I see lot of changes and we need to add new NuGet packages, I suggest you to migrate in VS, re-deploy the app again.

***.NET 7 Isolated Output:***

Copy the URL and execute the Function.

[image]
[image]